# Numpy Matrix Indexing Equivalence

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a matrix    `mat`:

```
 array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

I am wondering why    `mat[:3,1:2]` is:

```
 array([[ 2],
        [ 7],
        [12]])`
```

But    `mat[:3,1]` is:

```
 array([ 2, 7, 12])
```

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An integer, `i`, returns the same values as `i:i+1` except the dimensionality of the returned object is reduced by `1`. In particular, a selection tuple with the `p-th` element an integer (and all other entries `:`) returns the corresponding sub-array with dimension `N - 1`. If `N = 1` then the returned object is an array scalar. These objects are explained in Scalars.
>   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Thank you @Kasramvd